# Qsort array of structs

Tags: arrays, c, memory, struct, alloc

I have an array of structs that I'm adding entries into

```
typedef struct card
{
    char* name;
} card_t;
```

These are the names in the file: Stolen by the Fae, Eternal Isolation, Corpse Knight, Orzhov Enforcer

I have a qsort function that is supposed to sort all entries by alphabetical order. However it is not working.

```
// FUNCTION FOR QSORT()
int cmpname (const void *pa, const void *pb) {
    const card_t **p1 = pa;
    const card_t **p2 = pb;
    
    return strcmp((*p1(->name, (*p2)->name); 
}
```

```
#include "card.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
// FUNCTION FOR QSORT()
int cmpname (const void *pa, const void *pb) {
    const card_t *p1 = pa;
    const card_t *p2 = pb;
    
    return strcmp(p1->name, p2->name); 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {   
    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t bufsiz = 0;
    FILE *input_file;
    
    if((input_file = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
    {
        ssize_t result = getline(&buf, &bufsiz, input_file);
        int num_entries = 1;
        card_t **cards = NULL;
    
        int i = 0;
        int cardsaccum = 0;
        int id;
        char *name_duplicate;

        // GETS LINE FROM THE CSV FILE
        result = getline(&buf, &bufsiz, input_file);
        // WHILE THE FILE STILL HAS TEXT
        while (result > 0)
        {   // COPIES BUFFER TO SAVE THE MEMORY ADDRESS
            char *stringp = buf;
            // ALLOCATES MEMORY
            cards = realloc(cards, sizeof(card_t *) * num_entries);
            cards[cardsaccum] = malloc(sizeof(card_t));
            
            cards[cardsaccum]->name = strsep(&stringp, "\"");
            
            cardsaccum++;
            num_entries++;
            // MUST NULL THE BUFFER BEFORE GETLINE 
            buf = NULL;
            // NEXT LINE
            result = getline(&buf, &bufsiz, input_file);
            if(result == -1)
            {
                qsort(cards, cardsaccum - 1, sizeof(student_t *), cmpname);
                //printf("AFTER QSORT \n");
                //printf("\n");
                for(i = 0; i < cardsaccum;i++)
                {
                    printf("%s", cards[i]->name);
                }
            }
        }
        
        for(i=0; i < cardsaccum;i++)
        {
            free(cards[i]);
        }
        free(cards);
        free(buf);
        fclose(input_file);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "./parser: cannot open(%s%s%s): No such file or directory\n", "\"", argv[1], "\""); 
        return 1;
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
Corpse Knight
Eternal isolation
Stolen by the Fae
Orzhov Enforcer
```

If I have my qsort function correct, then Stolen by the Fae and Orzhov Enforcer should be switched. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers about the pointer deferencing are correct.

However, why are you passing in `length-1` instead of the actual number of elements?

```
qsort(cards, cardsaccum - 1, sizeof(char *), cmpname);
```

Should be:

```
qsort(cards, cardsaccum, sizeof(cards[0]), cmpname);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) funciton passess pointers to the elements to the comparison function.

In essence it calls your `cmpname` function like `cmpname(&cards[i], &cards[j])`.

And when every element in the array is a pointer, a pointer to it is a pointer to a pointer. Which means the variable `p1` and `p2` are incorrect in your function, leading to *undefined behavior*.

You need to use the correct types:

```
// FUNCTION FOR QSORT()
int cmpname (const void *pa, const void *pb) {
    const card_t **p1 = pa;  // These are pointer to the elements, and since each
    const card_t **p2 = pb;  // element is a pointer then these becomes pointers to pointers
    
    return strcmp((*p1)->name, (*p2)->name);  // Remember to dereference the pointers
}
```

You also have some other problems, like the number of elements argument for `qsort` should really be the number of elements in the array, not the top index. And why do you use `sizeof(char *)` as the element size?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation on the qsort!